# PHP convert date from EEST to UTC returns incorrect time by one hour

Tags: php, date, datetime

My PHP is converting the date incorrectly, the answer is off by one hour, I think the problem is that PHP thinks Europe/Vilnius is EEST time at this time, which should mean UTC+3, but its actually UTC+2 at this time. Any help how to solve this would be much appreciated. Have a great day!

My code:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vilnius');
$UTCtimezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$UTC_time = new DateTime($raw_date, $timezone); --> $raw_date is '2020-04-18 13:48:22'
```

At this time the date reads = 2020-04-18 13:50:05 EEST which is correct except for the EEST bit.

```
$UTC_time->setTimezone($UTCtimezone);
```

At this time date reads 2020-04-18 10:50:05 UTC which is incorrect now, because UTC time now should be 2020-04-18 11:50:05

Lots of karma points to anyone with any suggestions!

Comment: What's server's timezone? Is it the same as your current time zone? You can check with `echo date_default_timezone_get();`.

Comment: Perhaps it's relying to DST correct detection

Comment: @NickSurmanidze the answer is - UTC

Comment: @Banzay I think PHP is supposed to take care of that, or am I wrong? PHP V 7.2

Comment: As I know, you need to "manually" check current transition of your timezone. Smth like this: `$ts = timestamp(); $tz = "Europe/London";     $timezone = new \DateTimeZone($tz);  $transition = $timezone->getTransitions($ts);` and then `$transition[0]["isdst"]` will show wether you need to shift current time value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Europe/Vilnius is using EET (Eastern European Time) right now (2020-03-19), which is UTC+2.
On 2020-03-29 Europe/Vilnius will change to Daylight Saving Time EEST (Eastern European Summer Time), which is UTC+3.
Your example date 2020-04-18 is after that change, so it'll be 3 hours ahead of UTC.
Try todays date and the same code should show a 2 hour difference between Europe/Vilnius and UTC.

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, yes that is correct! Thank you!